# i am using webdriver io with cucumber and waitfordisplayed function is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, webdriver, cucumber, webdriverwait

This below function that i have created.

```
    export function waitForDisplayed(selector: string, falseCase: string): void {
    const ms = 20000;
    $(selector).waitForDisplayed(ms, !!falseCase);
    }
```

if i write feature file and pass the element in the feature file, it waits for element to be displayed and pass the test:

Below is the example of feature and step

And I expect that element "[id=email]" becomes displayed

```
    When(/^I expect that element "([^"]*)?" becomes( not)* displayed$/,
    waitForDisplayed,
    );
```

but if i write my feature file and pass the element in the step file

Below is the example.

I expect that element becomes displayed

```
    When(/^I expect that element becomes displayed$/, () => 
    waitForDisplayed(loginPage.inputEmail,'not');
    });
```

it passes the step but next test step fails since it did not wait for the element to be displayed.

Any suggestion please!!!